# Reverse order of items in a Row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable component that represent a message.
Each message can either be incoming or outgoing, depending on that I would like to reverse all items in my message component.

The only way I found is to force a RTL layout, however it leads to text being reversed too.
[image: Example]

Is there any other way around this?

`MessageView.kt`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MessageView(
    message: Message
) = Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
) {

    val (isIncoming) = message

    val direction = if (isIncoming) {
        LayoutDirection.Ltr
    } else {
        LayoutDirection.Rtl
    }

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalLayoutDirection provides direction
    ) {
        MessageViewContent(message)
    }

}

@Composable
private fun MessageViewContent(
    message: Message
) = Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
) {

    val (isIncoming, text, at) = message

    val background: Color
    val textColor: Color
    val timeColor: Color
    val alignment: Alignment.Horizontal
    val textAlignment: TextAlign

    if (isIncoming) {
        background = Color(0xFFEFEFEF)
        textColor = Color(0xFF000000)
        timeColor = Color(0xFF929292)
        alignment = Alignment.End
        textAlignment = TextAlign.Start
    } else {
        background = Color(0xFFE0727F)
        textColor = Color(0xFFFEFEFE)
        timeColor = Color(0xB3FEFEFE)
        alignment = Alignment.Start
        textAlignment = TextAlign.End
    }

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(40.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape),
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
        contentDescription = null
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(12.dp))

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1F, fill = false)
            .wrapContentWidth()
            .background(
                color = background,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
            )
            .padding(4.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = alignment
    ) {

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp),
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = textColor
            ),
            text = text
        )

        Text(
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 10.sp,
                color = timeColor,
                textAlign = textAlignment
            ),
            text = "${at.hour}:${at.minute}",
        )

    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(60.dp))

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I figured out a solution
One can create a custom Horizontal Arrangement which uses code from already existing `End` arrangement.

`HorizontalArrangementExts.kt`

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.LayoutDirection

val Arrangement.Reverse: Arrangement.Horizontal
    get() = ReverseArrangement

object ReverseArrangement : Arrangement.Horizontal {

    override fun Density.arrange(
        totalSize: Int,
        sizes: IntArray,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        outPositions: IntArray
    ) = if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr) {
        placeRightOrBottom(totalSize, sizes, outPositions, reverseInput = true)
    } else {
        placeLeftOrTop(sizes, outPositions, reverseInput = false)
    }

    // Had to copy function from sources because it is marked internal
    private fun placeRightOrBottom(
        totalSize: Int,
        size: IntArray,
        outPosition: IntArray,
        reverseInput: Boolean
    ) {
        val consumedSize = size.fold(0) { a, b -> a + b }
        var current = totalSize - consumedSize
        size.forEachIndexed(reverseInput) { index, it ->
            outPosition[index] = current
            current += it
        }
    }

    // Had to copy function from sources because it is marked internal
    private fun placeLeftOrTop(size: IntArray, outPosition: IntArray, reverseInput: Boolean) {
        var current = 0
        size.forEachIndexed(reverseInput) { index, it ->
            outPosition[index] = current
            current += it
        }
    }

    // Had to copy function from sources because it is marked private
    private inline fun IntArray.forEachIndexed(reversed: Boolean, action: (Int, Int) -> Unit) {
        if (!reversed) {
            forEachIndexed(action)
        } else {
            for (i in (size - 1) downTo 0) {
                action(i, get(i))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found your answer looking for a similar issue, I ended up having a list of composables and invoking them in a loop reversing the list or not accordingly, something similar to this:

```
Row {
    val composableList: List<@Composable () -> Unit> = listOf(
        { Text("first") },
        { Text("second") },
        { Text("third") }
    )

    if (showReversed) {
        composableList.reversed().forEach { it() }
    } else {
        composableList.forEach { it() }
    }
}
```